# Kotlin AsyncPriorityQueue

Tags: kotlin, priority-queue

Unbounded threadsafe suspending priority queue

1. Items are ordered by an integer priority value passed into the enqueue() method
2. dequeue() retrieves and removes the head of the queue or suspends until an item is available
3. enqueue(item, priority) inserts an item into the queue. suspends while aquiring a lock

Instead of using low level kotlin coroutine primitives to suspend when dequeue() is called
on an empty queue, I create a new CompletableDeferred, add it to a queue of outstanding
promises, then await it. When the next item is enqueued, a CompletableDeferred is popped
from the queue and completed. The close() method cancels all outstanding promises

The class is used internally, so I didn't bother with the standard Queue interface.

Am I missing anything here that might cause a problem?

````kotlin
package com.something.something

import kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

class AsyncQueueClosedError : RuntimeException("Queue is closed")

class AsyncPriorityQueue<T> : AutoCloseable {
    val closed get() = isClosed.get()
    val complete get() = isComplete.get() && items.size == 0

    private val isClosed = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private val isComplete = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private val items = PriorityQueue<Prioritized<T>> { o1, o2 -> o1.priority.compareTo(o2.priority) }
    private val lock = Mutex()
    private val promises = ArrayDeque<CompletableDeferred<T>>()

    override fun close() {
        if (!isClosed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            isComplete.set(true)
            runBlocking {
                lock.withLock {
                    for (p in promises) {
                        p.completeExceptionally(AsyncQueueClosedError())
                    }
                    promises.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun completeAdding() {
        if (isComplete.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            if (items.size == 0) {
                close()
            }
        }
    }

    private val key = object : Any() {}

    suspend fun dequeue(): T {
        lock.lock(key)
        return try {
            val item = items.poll()
            if (item == null) {
                if (isComplete.get()) {
                    close()
                    throw AsyncQueueClosedError()
                }
                val promise = CompletableDeferred<T>()
                promises.add(promise)
                lock.unlock(key)
                promise.await()
            } else {
                lock.unlock(key)
                item.item
            }
        } finally {
            if (lock.holdsLock(key)) lock.unlock(key)
        }
    }

    suspend fun enqueue(item: T, priority: Int) {
        if (isComplete.get()) throw AsyncQueueClosedError()

        lock.withLock {
            promises.poll()
                ?.complete(item)
                ?: items.add(Prioritized(item, priority))
        }
    }

    suspend fun size() = lock.withLock { items.size }
    private class Prioritized<T> constructor(val item: T, val priority: Int)
}
```
````